The physical intuition about the Kramers-Wannier duality
I understand the Mathematics about the Kramers-Wannier duality of 2D Ising model, but I'm looking for some physical intuition.
In my point of view, the essence of equilibrium statistical physics is the Competition between Entropy and Energy. At low temperature, energy dominates, and at high temperature, entropy dominates.
Since the low-temperature regime (ordered) and the high-temperature regime (disordered) are completely different, how can there be an exactly correspondence (duality) between them? Are there some physical intuition about this duality? And how can these physical intuition be extended to other model systems? (Or, how do they fail when applied to other systems) And in general, if there is duality in a model, what features do the model possess?

I don't think there is any deep "intuition" behind it: it's more of a combinatorial coincidence. Concerning the fact that there is a mapping between the high and low temperature regimes, notice that (apart from the free energies) this duality relates quantities of a very different nature, such as the low-temperature surface tension and the high-temperature rate of exponential decay of the 2-point function. As for the free energy itself, I don't think that it is much more than an accidental symmetry of the planar model.

You might however be interested in the way this duality manifests in the random cluster representation of the model: there, the duality takes a much stronger form, as it maps any low-temperature configuration to a high-temperature configuration (and vice versa). It might also be somewhat easier to understand why such a duality is reasonable (it is in fact quite obvious for the random-cluster model with parameter $q=1$, that is, Bernoulli percolation).
